# Informações não são Carregadas no MODAL Editar Após Paginar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-datatables, datatable

Bom dia Galera,

estou com uma dúvida e gostaria de saber se poderiam me ajudar...

Nessa primeira img, tenho uma tabela feita com data table com uma lista de cadastros, e cada um deles tem a opção de editar e excluir.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após eu clicar no botão de editar ele traz as informações do mesmo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui tudo Ok.

Ai vamos para outra pagina 
Como podem ver tudo certo também.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém após clicar em editar nesta outra página os dados não são carregados ! Gostaria de saber o porque que acontece isso ?

Me parece que após eu passar para outra página ele perde os eventos, não sei Rsrs
Gostaria de uma ajuda ;-)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito Grato.

Comment: Se vc colocar seu código ajuda bastante, porque existem várias possibilidades de erros - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Outra coisa, se vc apertar F12 no seu navegador, vai aparecer os erros de Javascript na aba Console.

Comment: Sim, F12 e depois ver na tab Console se há erros de javascript. Para além disso, o código que é executado para mostrar este modal, e como/onde vai buscar os dados vai ajudar a localizar o(s) problema(s).

Answer (score 0):

Penso que isto te ajudará:

```
<?php
                           while ($mm = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                               echo '<tr>';
                               echo '<td>'.$mm['id_variavel'].'</td>';
                               echo '<td>
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                   <a data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#exampleModal"
                                        data-whatever="'.$mm['id_variavel'].' ">Atualizar</a>
                                    </button>
                                    </td>';
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                }
                                $result->close();
                            ?>

    <script>
            $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
                var recipient = button.data('whatever') 
                var modal = $(this);
                var dataString = 'id=' + recipient;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "edit-modal.php", //para o ficheiro de criação do modal
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            modal.find('.dash').html(data);
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
            })
        </script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas no meu caso seria em c#